# Decompile unity coroutine(ienumerator) correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, decompiler

I'm creating game with unity, I found my old game that project was deleted, and wanna get full C# code from there.
I've used ILSpy to decompile to get it, everything was decompiled fine except coroutine(ienumerator). It decompile like C__Iterator, not correctly.(I've tried this with current project. Not decompile correctly)
I think it's because of Iterator Block..Is there any tool that decompile it correctly?
Is there any way to decompile coroutine(ienumerator) correctly?

Comment: You should read Unity EULA before coming on a public forum asking about decomposing an application. It could be illegal.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no application that will decompile correctly the `IEnumerator` because this statement is syntactic sugar. This means that when the compiler find an iterator block it transalte the block iterator in something more complex that the disassembler is not able to reconstruct in the original way.